Is it a good practice to call rest controller function in another rest controller function of the same controller based on request type?
Let's assume, I have 2 REST Endpoints and the second of them calls internally first one. The POST endpoint will behave like normal GET endpoint, but because of very large Set of dependentCategories, I cannot use is as query param, thus I choose to use POST in meaning of GET. Another problem is, I have to react different if dependentCategories is empty Set or if is null.
Is this whole concept an antipattern? Does exist better solution for such an example? Maybe should I just call other methods in Service, so that GET Endpoint is not dependent on POST endpoint?
@RestController
public class CategoriesController {

    @PostMapping("/categories/{productNo}") 
    ResponseEntity<?> getCategories(@PathVariable final String productNo,
                                    @RequestBody final Set<String> dependentCategories) {
        //some logic
    };

    @GetMapping("/categories/{productNo}")
    ResponseEntity<?> getCategories(@PathVariable final String productNo) {
        return this.getCategories(productNo, null); // or empty Set instead of null
    };

}


No. Create a separate method, put the common code on it and call on both controllers.

It's better to separate them and whatever diffrence in logic you have between both endpoints can be implemented in service layer. Or you can create one endpoint (POST) and check dependentCategories if null to decide with logic will be used.
